# Create new variable based on POSIxct value <

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I need to create a new variable: `version` based on the Time/Date in the column StartDate. StartDate is `POSIxct` format.

Everything before `2018-03-29 18:52:47` should be have `version` coded as 1.
Everything after `2018-03-29 18:52:47` (inclusive) should have `version` coded as 2. 
(Time zone is Europe/Madrid)

```
RespondentID    StartDate
170721984   3/29/2018 9:26:05
170721984   3/29/2018 11:14:55
170721984   3/29/2018 18:52:47
170721984   3/30/2018 14:15:08
170721984   3/30/2018 17:43:17
```

I can sort the dataframe and just resort to making everything before row x v1 and after v2 but I don't want to "cheat." Thanks in advance for any help, I'm very new to R and am trying to stick with it and not run back to SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution, it uses two simple `ifelse`, with `dplyr` `library`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat$Date <- as.POSIXct(dat$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
# this is needed in order to use the correct date format

dat %>% 
  mutate(v1 = ifelse(Date < "2018-03-29 18:52:47", 1, 0),
         v2 = ifelse(Date >= "2018-03-29 18:52:47", 1, 0)) # this creates v1,v2

# RespondentID                Date v1 v2
# 1    170721984 2018-03-29 09:26:00  1  0
# 2    170721984 2018-03-29 11:14:00  1  0
# 3    170721984 2018-03-29 18:52:00  1  0
# 4    170721984 2018-03-30 14:15:00  0  1
# 5    170721984 2018-03-30 17:43:00  0  1
```

Data used:

```
tt <- "RespondentID Date Hour
    170721984   03/29/2018 9:26:05
    170721984   03/29/2018 11:14:55
    170721984   03/29/2018 18:52:47
    170721984   03/30/2018 14:15:08
    170721984   03/30/2018 17:43:17"

dat <- read.table(text=tt, header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(Date = trimws(paste0(Date, " ", Hour))) %>% # this just puts Date as in your example
  select(-Hour)

# RespondentID                Date
# 1    170721984  03/29/2018 9:26:05
# 2    170721984 03/29/2018 11:14:55
# 3    170721984 03/29/2018 18:52:47
# 4    170721984 03/30/2018 14:15:08
# 5    170721984 03/30/2018 17:43:17
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my initial prompt. I need one variable coded binary as either v1/1 or v2/2, not two variables v1 and v2 coded each as binary 1,0. This code gives me the error: Unknown or uninitialised column. when I check the new variables v1 or v2. :(

Comment: Please add the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution from lubridate will help you.

```
time <- read.csv("stack_Time.csv")
library(lubridate)
time$StartDate<- mdy_hms(time$StartDate) 

time$flag <- ifelse(time$StartDate < mdy_hms("03-29-2018 18:52:47"),"v1","v2")
```

This will give you required output.

Comment: Thanks. This codes creates the new variable for me but codes everything as "NA"

Comment: no it is working fine in my pc please check date formate in your pc whether it is mm-dd or mm/dd . It might be the case

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of the two responses as I couldn't get the 
strobe$StartDate <- mdy_hms(strobe$StartDate) code to work.

library(lubridate) 
strobe$StartDate <- as.POSIXct(strobe$StartDate, format = "%y-%m/-%d %H:%M:%S")
strobe$version <- ifelse(strobe$StartDate < mdy_hms("03-29-2018 18:52:47"),1,2)